# pytest: How to parametrize a fixture based on command line arguments?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have a bunch of test cases that are yielded by a fixture. I want the fixture to selectively yield test cases based on command line parameters. I tried a couple of ways in vain.

Using the **params** argument to the fixture decorator: I don't have access to the 'request' context.

Using **pytest_generate_tests()**: I fetch the command line arguments using the metafunc object context and create the fixture to parametrise the test like [this](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example). But, I'm worried pytest_generate_tests() is run for every test and the whole point of having a fixture is lost. Is this the case?

I'm a little new to pytest, so I might not be using the framework properly as well. So, I'm open to other ways of making this work. Basically I want to parametrize my test based on command line args and they need to be fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest_cmdline_main](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_cmdline_main) like this

```
def pytest_cmdline_main(config):
    option = config.getoption('--your-option')
    if option:
        # use the option to modify fixture data
```

pytest_generate_tests is useful to generate fixture values on the fly.